# Retrofit2 (Android) - How to send form-data along POST method

Tags: android, request, http-post, retrofit, retrofit2

*P.s: Changed references for security matters.

I'm trying to get json from a server but it requires form-data in the body of request, like this:
[image]

It works when tested in postman, but I just can't figure out how to do this using retrofit2.

Beans:

```
public class Y {

@SerializedName("id")
private int yId;
@SerializedName("name")
private String yName;


//...
}


public class YList {

@SerializedName("ys")
private List<Y> ys;

//...
}
```

The service interface is like this:

```
public interface YService {
@POST("y")
Call<YList> getY()

public static final YService serviceY = new Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl("http://example.com.br/api/x/")
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
        .build()
        .create(YService.class);
}
```

And REST method:

```
YService yService = YService.serviceY;




    yService.getY().enqueue(new Callback<YList>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<YList> call, Response<YList> response) {

            if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                //...
            } else {

                //...

            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<YList> call, Throwable t) {

            //...

        }
    });'
```

Postman JSON result:

```
{
"auth": {
  "validation": true
},
"ys": [
{
  "id": 1,
  "name": "#"
}
]
}
```

Comment: where is your interface? Where is the Call<?> that you have? put more information

Comment: Code added. Hope someone can help me. @KostasDrak

Comment: did you read about the @Body retrofit annotation?

Comment: I tried using getY(@Body AuthRequest.Auth info). In which AuthRequest has an "Auth" inner class with email and password attributes and that didn't work. I guess it's because there's no reference to form-data key name?  @KostasDrak

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to find a solution, which turned out to be a lot easier than I thought.

Just crate a class called AuthRequest like this:

```
public class AuthRequest {

    private static final String TAG = "Auth";
    private static final String EMAIL = "email";
    private static final String PASSWORD = "pass";


    //creates a json-format string
    public static String createAuthJsonString(){

        String info = "{\"auth\":{\"email\":\""+EMAIL+"\",\"password\":\""+PASSWORD+"\"}}";


        Log.i(TAG,info);

        return info;
    }

}
```

Just add @FormUrlEncoded to @Post and put @Field key and value inside method call:

```
@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("ys")//endpoint
Call<YList> getY(@Field("info") String info);


// Connection url.
public static final YService serviceY = new Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl("http://example.com.br/api/x/")
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
        .build()
        .create(YService.class);
```

Using getY() method:

```
    final YService yService = YService.serviceY;
    //...
    yService.getY(AuthRequest.createAuthJsonString()).enqueue(new 
        Callback<YList>() {

        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<YList> call, Response<YList> response) {

            if (response.isSuccessful()) {
              //...

            } else {

               //...
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<YList> call, Throwable t) {

            //...

        }


    });



}
```

Returned YList from json perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

[Retrofit2 Body with from-data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hGCgj.png)

```
@FormUrlEncoded 
@POST("xxx")//endpoint
Call<xxxx> getxxx(@Field("phone") String phone);
```